# Remove / Hide title from android support library actionbar

Tags: android-actionbar, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I want to use just the application logo instead of {application logo} + {title (text)} on android support action bar, app logo shows perfectly but app name shows up as title next to the logo.

I have tried tried following already:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

This is not the best solution as title of the application is visible when application is loading up and is removed once app (or layout) is loaded completely.

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/darkblue</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">0sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#00000000</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="background">@color/darkblue</item>
 </style>
```

This also doesn't have any effect on the application title on the support action bar.

Please suggest some alternatives, Thanks

Comment: Down vote without reason? seriously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following changes to MyActionBar Style works perfectly!

```
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">

        <item name="android:background">@color/darkblue</item>
        <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|useLogo</item>
        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="background">@color/darkblue</item>
        <item name="displayOptions">showHome|useLogo</item> 

 </style>
```